# Required attribute inside Jquery generated output

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a script where I create an input element. How can I put require inside it? and what is the difference between setting an input and making it variable and append it to a div and still put an attribute required?

Javascript code:

```
$("#myVar").append(
'<input name="name" class="myClass">');
```

JQuery code:

```
var input = $('<input>', { id: myID', name: 'name', type: 'text', class: 'myClass', focusin: function() { $(this).val(''); } }).appendTo('#myVar'); ?
```

I found a post just like this and I found this useful for me. How should I required this? attribute doesn't work

HTML:

```
<div id="myVar"></div>
```

Comment: please clarify your second question.

Comment: Hi, did you tried `required :'required'` ?

Comment: Hi, not yet, where will I put that attribute?

Comment: like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vf6L45m0/)  and add only if you need required attribute .

Comment: Ahh okay yes I did that but my form is not reading it as required, why is that? I tried creating a form.

Comment: working fine with form ..check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vf6L45m0/1/) click on submit button without typing anything inside input you will see error message.

Comment: Ahh okay now I get it, type="button" is not reading it right? so I should use submit instead of button?

Comment: yes then only your form will submit .

Comment: @Swati Sorry for the inconvenience but it is not working when I created a modal because I put the type="submit" inside modal button. So the first event is I click a button where it will pop up my modal and then submit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228564/discussion-between-swati-and--san).

Comment: Hi @Swati, Update of what I did is I disabled my button if no input has been made so that it will not proceed to submit, required did not work for me because of the button type="button". Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write required attribute.

```js
$("#myVar").append(
'<input name="name" class="myClass" required />');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myVar"></div>
```

Comment: What if like this code, var input = $('<input>', { id: myID', name: 'name', type: 'text', class: 'myClass', focusin: function() { $(this).val(''); } }).appendTo('#myVar'); ? I found a post just like this and I found this useful for me. How should I required this? attribute doesn't work

Comment: $("#myVar").append( '<input name="name" type="text" class="myClass" focusin="function() { $(this).val(\'\');" id="myID" class="myClass" required />' );

Comment: you can use the above for that.

Answer (score 0):

just include required method in your input field.

`$("#myVar").append( '<input name="name" class="myClass" required />');`

And please clarify your second question as it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Editted my question